# jQuery word counter - exclude string in brackets

Tags: jquery, regex, match

i have an jQuery function for word counting in textarea field. Everithing works fine, but i need exclude words enclosed in triple brackets - [[[for example this string]]] from counter. How do I modify the regular expression to make it work?

```
    function word_count(field) {
        var number = 0;
        var matches = $(field).val().match(/\b/g);

        if (matches) {
            number = matches.length / 2;
        }
        wordCounts[field] = number;
        var wordCounter = 0;
        $.each(wordCounts, function(k, v) {
            wordCounter += v;

        });
        return wordCounter;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude words in brackets by making

```
var matches = $(field).val().replace(/\[\[\[.*\]\]\]/g, '').match(/\b/g);
```

This way you'll remove any string in the brackets and count the other one.

Comment: useful answer. how can i write it if i want to count it as 4 words whenever a bracket will come. what should i write instead of these ''.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove enclosed text before further processing. Use this:

```
text = text.replace(/\[\[\[[^\]]*\]\]\]/g, "");
```

Comment: You forgot to place '/g' - global flag in the end of your replace regexp